# does this hold for any conservative vector field?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

A vector field in n dimensions is path independent if for every output there is a surface of an n dimensional  shell on which the output is the same. I think this is true intuitively because the line integral through a thin shell doesn't depend on the angle of the line. However, I'm having a trouble deciding how to compute the actual integral.

An example of is the inverse square force law, whose output can be parametrised by a two dimensional spherical shell.

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean when you say that a vector field is "parameterized by a shell". That's not a commonly used phrase.

Comment: My best guess is that you're trying to say that conservative fields are the gradient of some potential function. However, if you had that in mind, I'd think that the computation would be intuitive.

Comment: Do you meant to say path-independent or "surface-independent"? By "surface of an $n$-dimensional shell", do you mean boundary of some $n$-dimensional objects?

Comment: Yes, but now I'm confused by the meaning of potential function. But in that case i'd be asking whether 'if a field is the gradient of a potential function, then it is conservative' which is true because all gradients are conservative. But the question then becomes show that this is a gradient of some potential function

Comment: I think you need to clarify exactly what you mean. As it is now it's a bit vague.